# Python string Not working (==)

Tags: python

Here is my syntax:

```
input("Has the phone got wet?")

if input is "yes".strip('\n'):
    print("that's the problem")
else:
    print("okay")
```

Comment: But your example does not contain ==. Also, do tag your question correctly; many answerers only listen on certain tags.

Comment: `is` is not same as `==`.

Comment: `"yes".strip('\n')` is just `"yes"`

Comment: You need to assign to variable `user_input  = input("Has the phone got wet?")` ... `if user_input == "yes":`

Comment: This is happening because input method will try to parse the input provided at the terminal with eval. If the input provided is not a literal like a number or a string in quotes then an error will be thrown. See answer below.

Comment: What exactly does *" not working"* mean? Give a [mcve]. If nothing else, you're applying `str.strip` to the wrong side of the comparison, comparing to a function not its return value and comparing by identity not equality.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use == instead of is:

```
answer = input("Has the phone got wet?")
if answer == "yes":
    print("that's the problem")
else:
    print("okay")
```

Comment: for python2 use raw_input instead of just input

Comment: You are testing if `input` the <built-in function input> equals `"yes"`

Comment: No in fact - "If the prompt argument is present, it is written to standard output without a trailing newline. The function then reads a line from input, converts it to a string (stripping a trailing newline), and returns that." - https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input

Comment: I'm afraid you are completely wrong, you need to store the returned value as a variable and then compare this to `"yes"` (see my comment on the question)

Comment: Oh yes, i was definitely thinking about smth else ) You are right, of course

Answer (score -3):

When you use `input`, pass the values at the terminal in quotes. Like 

`Has the phone got wet?"yes"`

and not like this:

`Has the phone got wet?yes`

You can use `raw_input` if you would rather not type quotes.